# MongoDB Difference in Sharding Distribution

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I ran two runs for the same set of data and wondering about the difference in sharding distribution. What are the possible reasons for the different balancing? Shard key is:

```
{  "_id" : "newprov",  "partitioned" : true,  "primary" : "shard0002" }
        newprov.hpc_provenance
                shard key: { "jobID" : 1, "user" : 1 }
```

[image: First run]
[image: Second run]

Comment: Sounds like you have a bad shard key causing clustering of data on the first shard possibly, sending all writes there if I read your question right

Comment: @Sammaye: Shard key are the same.

Comment: What is your exact scenario?  Did you drop and recreate the sharded database inserting identical data in the same order?  I'm not clear what your charts are meant to illustrate (what is run 1 vs run 2?).

Comment: @Stennie: Yes, identical data, same order of inserts. Charts are meant to illustrate difference in the distribution for different shards. 3 Shards used in total and charts show the distribution on each shard with total amount of documents on x-axis. Let me know if this is unclear still.

Comment: So there is one chart for each run, and the counts are sampled over time? Is the size referring to data size or storage size? How are you getting the count of documents, and how many `mongos` processes are you inserting into? Given that MongoDB [preallocates storage](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/storage/#why-are-the-files-in-my-data-directory-larger-than-the-data-in-my-database) it's possible for there to be a difference in the file size if one shard has needed to create a new disk extent earlier than the others.

Comment: @Stennie: One chart for each run, data is inserted into DB. After a million document inserts, the stats from db.stats() are noted. Size is from dataSize in db.stats(). Count of documents is from querying the count in the only collection in the DB. I am running one mongos with 3 shards.